# expand array to arguments list in perl

Tags: perl, arguments, perl-module

I have something like the following code

```
my @array = ["hello","hi","fish"];
sub this_sub {
  my $first = $_[0];
  my $second = $_[1];
  my $third = $_[2];
}
this_sub(@array);
```

How can I make the array expand into an argument list so that 
first, second and third will get the value from the strings in the array. like below.

- first = "hello"
- second = "hi"
- third = "fish"

Comment: The truth is that you *cannot* prevent an array from expanding into an argument list unless you fiddle around with prototypes.

Comment: WOW! perl's mysub (a, b, c) is LITERALLY the same as mysub @mylist. AMAZING. This is so cool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is wrong. To assign a list to an array, enclose it in normal parentheses:

```
my @array = ("hello", "hi", "fish");
```

Square brackets define an anonymous array, i.e. a referenco to a list, which is a scalar:

```
my $array_ref = ["hello", "hi", "fish"];
```

If you want to send a reference, you have to dereference it in the sub:

```
sub this_sub {
    my ($first, $second, $third) = @{ $_[0] };
}
```

Comment: That is very helpfull I will try it out and be back soon!

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes beneficial to be able to expand the array into an argument list since one usually do not have access to the subroutine in question.  Here's my solution.

```
sub test_sub($$$) {
    my ($a,$b,$c) = @_;
    say "$a $b $c";
}
my @array = ('happy', 'birthday', 'to you');
my $eval_str = 'test_sub(' join ', ', @array . ')';
eval $eval_str;
```

It is somewhat ugly, hopefully someone else can suggest an improved version.